# How to change output date format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date-format, countdowntimer

I want to use **jquery.flipCountDown Plugin**, There's a problem in this plugin based on Date Format, that's why It doesn't work in IE , FireFox and Safari too.

Date Format should be like this in this **JavaScript Flip Count Down** :

```
beforeDateTime:'2017/10/10 00:00:01'
```

but If the date format will change to Standard Format, it doesn't work in other browsers.

Standard Format:

```
2017-10-10
```

The problem is related to **00:00:01**

In IE, Safari Count Down is 0.0.0.0
When I remove it, then it will work on all browsers but Count Down not working correctly.

> How can I change date format based on 00:00:01?

Comment: Can you use `moment.js`?

Comment: you can replace "-" with "/" like '2017-10-10 00:00:01'.replace(/-/g, '/')

Comment: Standard format based on query is like that, I can't change it.

Comment: http://coder.gairainfotech.com/2014/06/converting-mysql-date-to-readable-format-in-javascript/

Comment: use http://momentjs.com/